# Clicking HTML button programmatically

Tags: vb.net

There is a website which has 4 web pages. On first page there is a button, On 2nd page there are also some buttons, on 3rd page there is also a single button, and 4th page also contained a single button. Problem is that my code programmatically clicks the button of first page 2nd page and 3rd page. But is is not clicking the button on 4th page programmatically. How can I enable my code to do that? Please suggest a reliable solution for this .. The HTML code of the button is given below

```
<FORM NAME='form1' METHOD='post' action='/dflogin.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtId' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassId' value='1'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtPsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtLog' value='0'><h6 align='right'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Next' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></h6></FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code clicks a button programmatically, you should be able to adapt this to what you need and hopefully it should work for you.

```
  For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons 
      If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Next") Then 
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click") 
        Exit For 
      End If 
  Next
```